# function me devuelve null en modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un botón de editar datos de una tabla donde me redirecciona a una vista para editar los datos.

Y en esa vista tengo este codigo:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SucursalId, Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SucursalId).ToString(), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.DropDownList("SucursalId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control select2", @style ="width:100%" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SucursalId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Que es un select de las sucursales que tengo.

Y tengo otra función para Filtrar por Sucursales por medio del Id (esta función esta dentro de la vista y ya carga al momento de abrir)

```
function FiltrarSucursales(id) {
        var URL = '@Url.Action("SucursalesPorCliente", "Utilidades")';
        //Modelos/ModelosPorMarcas'; //$('#MarcaModeloId').data('ModeloListAction');
        $.getJSON(URL + '/' + id, function (data) {
            $('#SucursalId option').remove();
            //$.getJSON(URL, function (data) {
            var items;// = '<option>Seleccione Modelo</option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, sucursal) {
                items += "<option value='" + sucursal.Value + "'>" + sucursal.Text + "</option>";
                // state.Value cannot contain ' character. We are OK because state.Value = cnt++;
            });
            $('#SucursalId').html(items);
        });
    }

    FiltrarSucursales('@Model.Sucursal.ClienteId');
```

Donde por medio de otra función que tengo en el controlador busco la sucursal a filtrar por medio del id.

```
public JsonResult SucursalesPorCliente(int Id)
        {
            var Sucursales = db.Sucursales.Where(x => x.ClienteId == Id & x.Activo == true).OrderBy(x => x.Nombre);
            return Json(new SelectList(Sucursales, "SucursalId", "Nombre"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Todo bien hasta ahí pero, añadí otra vista para que en vez de que me cargue la vista se abra un modal.

Que es este que tengo aquí:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ContactoEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            @{ Html.RenderAction("_Edit", "Contactos"); }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lo cual al momento de abrir el modal me manda un error en la función que le pongo como, en la parte del llamado de la función `FiltrarSucursales('@Model.Sucursal.ClienteId');` que me dice que la

> referencia del objeto no esta instanciada de un objeto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba con Html.RenderPartial("_Edit",Model);

Comment: me dice que tiene que ser `Domain.Entities.Contacto` pero lo tengo como `@model IEnumerable<Domain.Entities.Contacto>`